# idn_to_ascii not working in PHP 5.4.16 CentOS6

Tags: php, centos, idn

right now I'm working with the idn_to_ascii function to convert some IDN domain names into ascii ones.

This code worked nice, until a customer used ß in his domain name:

```
idn_to_ascii( "teßt" );
```

This led to the wrong result of beeing converted to "tesst" - a little bit of researched and I found out that there was an update in the IDN 2008 to include ß as special convertable character. So the new call is

```
idn_to_ascii("teßt", IDNA_NONTRANSITIONAL_TO_ASCII, INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46);
```

Which works fine in our developement environment (XAMPP, Windows, PHP 5.4.16)

After I deployed it to our productive system, the result of the above code is "NULL", eventhough it's the exact same PHP 5.4.16 version, only that it's an CentOS6 system.

More interesting:

```
Production System:
var_dump(IDNA_NONTRANSITIONAL_TO_ASCII); => string(29) "IDNA_NONTRANSITIONAL_TO_ASCII"
var_dump(INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46); => string(23) "INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46"

Dev System:
var_dump(IDNA_NONTRANSITIONAL_TO_ASCII); => int(16)
var_dump(INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46); => int(1)
```

This clearly shows me that it's not including the definitions for the new standard, but it should, since libidn2 and php-intl are installed on the production system.

I hope you have any clues for me, since I dont know where to look else.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well I guess the obvious question is was the libidn on your production server updated after the 'ß' to 'ss' fix in 2008?

Comment: libidn is installed by default in CentOS6 and cannot be removed.
libidn2 was installed today, php-intl and php reinstalled after libidn2 got installed. Sadly it didn't have any effect